# Counting rows and columns for named ranges in vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to count the number of rows and columns in vba from a named range in excel. The row and column counts are then used in an 2D array to perform other calculations. The named range is "CF_Inputs" which is from A2:Z60 in a worksheet called "Price_Volumes_Inputs". I can't seem get a row & column count using named ranges, so I used the code below with the offset method to count rows and columns. Is there a way to do this using the actual named range? I'm new to the whole programming thing, so I apologize for the simple question.

```
Dim Inputs As Variant    
Sheets("Price_Volumes_Input").Activate

Inputs = Range("A2", Range("Z2").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight))
```

Comment: `Worksheets("Price_Volumes_Inputs").Range("CF_Inputs").Rows.Count`

Comment: Thanks for the feedback very helpful.  I was able to use the code for a modified row and column count, and also to populate a dynamic array.  Sheets("Input").Activate
    Dim Row_Count As Long
    Dim Column_Count As Long
    Row_Count = Worksheets("Input").Range("CF_Inputs").Rows.Count
    Column_Count = Worksheets("Input").Range("CF_Inputs").Columns.Count
    Inputs = Worksheets("Input").Range("CF_Inputs", Range("CF_Inputs").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight))

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to the world of VBA programming.  If you're going to be doing Excel VBA programming then you need to bookmark Chip Pearson's website.  I've found it very useful.  The link is http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/MainPage.aspx

There are many ways to do this.  For example one simple way is

```
Dim dataRows As Long
Dim dataCols As Long
Dim workArray as Variant

With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Price_Volumes_Input").Range("CF_Inputs")
    dataRows = .Rows.Count
    dataCols = .Columns.Count
End With

Dim workArray() As Variant
Redim workArray(dataRows, dataCols) as Variant
Dim i as Long, j as Long
For i = 0 to dataRows - 1
    For j = 0 to dataCols - 1
        'do the calculations
    Next j
Next i
```